Spectral sequence and De Rham cohomology of quotient manifolds
Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated discrete group(possibly infinite, likewise $\mathbb{Z}$) smoothly acting on $X$ freely and $X/G$ be a manifold.
Then, I would like to know the cohomology of $X/G$ in terms of the cohomologies of $X$ and $G$.
We could restate the problem into the case of fiber bundle whose fiber is $G$, and I realize that the spectral sequence could help to solve the problem.
However, I couldn't find the solution of this specific case. Most case is focusing on $G$ is finite, or $X/G$ is simply connected or Wang's sequence, Gysin sequence, more general fibrations, etc.
So, here is the question, what reference is dealt with the general theory of the de Rham cohomology of $X/G$? Is it still too complicate to describe about it under this setting?
If it's impossible to say in one theorem, then I would like to know the special case when the dimension of $X/G$ is less than, or equal to $4$.

As you say, you really want the Serre spectral sequence applied $X \to X/G \to BG$ with the understanding that $H^*(BG, (-))$ is the group cohomology of $G$. In general, when $G$ is not abelian, this will be more complicated because now you need to worry about "local coefficients" which involves understanding representations of $G$.

This is sometimes called the homotopy orbit spectral sequence because it really involves $(X \times EG)/G$, but when $G$ acts freely this is homotopy equivalent to $X/G$. You can of course say something via de rham cohomology but in general $BG$ is not a manifold (infinite dimensional), but you can always use the comparison

@AndresMejia Thanks for the comment, then from that point of view, I have two questions. One is, if $BG$ is a manifold, like for example $G = \pi_1(M)$, then are there some simple description? Second is, does  Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence gives a same result as we get from the Serre spectral sequence in this case? I'm not seeing about the former one, so I woud like to know the result about it. I just know that EM spectral sequence is about the pullback bundle, and I think this is the appropriate case to apply it.

yeah it's basically the same thing in this case (eilenberg-moore.) Maybe it's worth just asking about the case you're interesting. when $G=\pi_1(M)$, $BG$ need not be a manifold.

@AndresMejia I believe I understand what you're saying now. So, $BG$ is a concept defined only up to homotopy equivalence, so it needs to be $M$ itself even if $M$ is a manifold. Thanks for the clarification!
